# Association learning on short messages

Tags: associations, machine-learning

I have a data set of short messages containing sender's name, recipient, the short message between a word and twenty words in length, as well as a class assigned spam/not spam. I would like to build a set of association rules based on this historical data. I was thinking of the Apriori algorithm but I don't know how to discretize the short message in order to run the algorithm over the data set. The goal is to extract rules that lead to spam/not spam classification

Answer (score 1):

Naive Bayes / SVM is better for this kind of classification. Just treat each word as a feature.